# Generate Dependency Graph for specific groupId

Tags: java, maven

I am using the [Depgraph Maven Plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin) and I'd like to ask if there's a way to limit the generated graph file (dot or gml) with those with a specific `groupId` e.g. `com.mycompany.*` pattern where only the dependencies within this package would be part of the graph.

I have tried both `depgraph:aggregate` and `depgraph:aggregate-by-groupid` but both results contains all the dependencies only organized into `groupId`

Which generated this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the README of the [depgraph plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin) (bottom of the page), you can use the `includes`/`excludes` parameters similar to Maven's `dependency` plugin. The plugin also provides more information on this in their [filtering wiki page](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin/wiki/Filtering).

Parameters in Maven are provided with `-D`, or in the configuration of your plugin. In case of command line you would use:

```
mvn depgraph:graph -Dincludes=com.mycompany*
```